# How to make a loop in HTML

Tags: html, loops

I have html file with a portfolio. Every portfolio item looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="img/portfolio-item-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1">
               <img src="img/portfolio-item-1.jpg">
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a easy and simple way to make a loop. So I create multple of these div's and each time the number changes. So the second time I have to get portfolio-item-2.

Comment: the least you will need is vanilla javascript.

Comment: HTML is a markup language. You need js.

Comment: HTML can not do such things. HTML is not a programming or scripting language. It is simply a markup language. You need JavaScript, PHP or some other scripting/programming language for that. Or simply copy, paste and manual editing.

Comment: You need [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/).  HTML is not made to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML isn't a programming language and doesn't have the ability to write loops. To do that you will need some other language to generate HTML, e.g. JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

You could use some JavaScript like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><div class="portfolio-item"><a href="img/portfolio-item-' + i + '.jpg" data-lightbox="image-' + i + '"><img src="img/portfolio-item-' + i + '.jpg"></a></div></div>'
}
```

Then you could just change `i < 10` to change how many items are output.

This example just outputs to the body tag, so you'd also need to change that to the container where you want these items output.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines HTML like this:

> HyperText Markup Language (HTML) is a markup language[1] for creating webpages

Wikipedia define a markup language like this:

> A markup language is a computer language. It is made up of a set of instructions, and of data. It is not the same as a programming language, as only programming languages can have if statements and other conditional statements.[1] The first markup languages were used for printing; there was the text, and there were instructions how the text should be printed.

Sources: [HTML](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [Markup language](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)

This means that things like loops cannot be done in HTML and you need something else.  Generally the easiest option is to use [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).  You can do various things with JavaScript include inserting images into web pages and the use of loops, controlling how a webpage works rather than being static.

For getting started I can recommend you a good free [tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/), but the section on [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) should also interest you.